# How to catch exceptions from botocore

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, botocore

I am getting the below error while using `boto3` with `Amazon SNS`. I want to catch `InvalidParameterException` only, how can I do the same?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Logger\Notification.py", line 279, in <module>
    Push.subscribe(token1, 'android')
  File "D:\Logger\Notification.py", line 119, in subscribe
    'Enabled': b'True'
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 310, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 599, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterException: An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the CreatePlatformEndpoint operation: Invalid parameter: Token Reason: Endpoint arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:252285631092:endpoint/GCM/Test/06c4448e-545b-312a-978f-98af5d5829e4 already exists with the same Token, but different attributes.
```

If I try to catch `InvalidParameterException`, it shows

```
NameError: global name 'InvalidParameterException' is not defined
```

I have imported `botocore`. Now if I try to catch `botorcore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterException` it shows.

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'InvalidParameterException'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `botocore` library generates several exceptions from a base class. Catch the baseclass:

```
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

try:    
    ...
except ClientError as e:
    ...
```

Inspect the `ClientError().response['Error']['Code']` to vary how you handle the exception, and just `raise` again if you want to ignore a specific error type. See the [*Error Handling* documentation](http://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client_upgrades.html#error-handling).